# Method for an item to reference its container

Tags: ruby

If I do the following, for example:

```
foo = ["bar"]
foo.keep_if {|n| foo.last.obect_id == n.object_id}
```

Is there another way I can refer to foo inside the block instead of naming it, something like "n.container"?

Comment: You could create your own objects that keep track of "containment"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. An object can appear in any number of containers (and there is no protocol for containers to tell objects, "Yo, I'mma contain you now"), so it isn't really practical. Just using the existing variable in your block is the cleanest way to do it.